# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with promise all

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was initially just running one query in node.js but I now need two sets of data so I ran two queries and used Promise.all like this:

```
 Promise.all([products, subcats]);
  res.status(200).json({
    products,
    subcats
  });
```

In React I have:

```
class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    products: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const catslug = this.props.match.params.catslug;
    const { data: products } = await getCatProducts(catslug);
    this.setState({ products: products });
  }
```

When I was only running the one query I was running this without any issue:

```
this.state.products.map(product => (
```

Now because I have the 2 queries I need to change it to:

```
this.state.products.products.map(product => (
```

But as soon as I do that I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

So, I changed it to this and now it works with no errors:

```
{this.state.products.products &&
this.state.products.products.map(product => (
```

My question is why did it work before without having to put in the ... && bit but now I have to use it with the Promise.all in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the initial shape of your state

```
state = {
    products: []
  };
```

You see this.state.products is already defined as an array, so it can be mapped over (despite being empty). However this.products.products is NOT an array, it is undefined, so trying to map will return the error you are seeing. The line you have entered

```
{this.state.products.products &&
this.state.products.products.map(product => (
```

checks that the array exists before attempting to map it (which wont evaluate to true until your async code finishes, and then the array is defined).

An alternative fix would be to set your initial state shape to match your final state shape. i.e

```
state ={
    products:{
        products:[]
    }
};
```

Or if you don't want the nested products property you can change

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const catslug = this.props.match.params.catslug;
    const { data } = await getCatProducts(catslug);
    this.setState({ products: data.products });
  }
```

and return to your old this.state.products.map()

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the following line:

```
const { data: products } = await getCatProducts(catslug);
```

If I understand correctly, when you were sending one value, you were sending it like:

```
res.status(200).json(products); // an array
```

But now you are sending an `object`, which further contains 2 arrays products and subcats.

What you have 2 do is add below changes to make it work:

```
const obj = await getCatProducts(catslug);
const products = obj.products
const subcats = obj.subcats
```